# How to make status bar transparent when using UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, uistatusbar

I was creating my own custom UISearchBar and UISearchController, following [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-search-bar-tutorial/) and I wanted to add my own background using searchBar.setBackgroundImage() but the problem is that the image doesn't span the status bar as well. So I get a white status bar that looks like this:

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

your give link project implemented:

first go to main.storyboard delete constraint of tableview top after set tableview y position  = 0 and set top constraint of tableview.

your search bar view height set in viewcontroller.swift file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the part where you set the search bar view height in the viewcontroller.swift file? How do I push the search bar, and all the stuff down?

Comment: find  you are set frame for search view and set height. or doesn't set your height default = 50.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

Comment: setStatusBarStyle(_:animated:)' was deprecated in iOS 9.0

Answer (score -3):

Set imageview "top space to superview" = -20.

Thanks